# How to get Objects from Array by condition?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, oop

This is my actual code:

```
public TerminalGui[] getTerminalGuis() {
    Components comps[] = this.getComponents();
    int i, j = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < comps.length ; i++ ) {
        if( comps[i] instanceof TerminalGui ) {
            j++;
        }
    }

    TerminalGui terminalGuis[j];
    int k = 0;
    for( Component c : comps ) {
        if( c instanceof TerminalGui ) {
            terminalGuis[k] = c;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return terminalGuis;
}
```

How to do better? I want to get all Objects from `this.getComponents()` which are instances of `TerminalGui` (interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
public TerminalGui[] getTerminalGuis() {
    Components comps[] = getComponents();
    List<TerminalGui> list = new ArrayList<TerminalGui>();

    if (comps == null) return null;

    for( Component c : comps ) {
        if( c instanceof TerminalGui ) {
            list.add(c);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new TerminalGui[list.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @NikolayKuznetsov is best as least code. But here your version corrected. So you recognize the possibilities.

```
public TerminalGui[] getTerminalGuis() {
    Component[] comps = this.getComponents();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
        if (comps[i] instanceof TerminalGui) {
            j++;
        }
    }

    TerminalGui[] terminalGuis = new TerminalGui[j];
    int k = 0;
    for (Component c : comps) {
        if (c instanceof TerminalGui) {
            terminalGuis[k] = c;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return terminalGuis;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can work with a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
public TerminalGui[] getTerminalGuis() {
   Components comps[] = this.getComponents();
   List<TerminalGui> terminals = new ArrayList<TerminalGui>();
   int i;

      for( i = 0; i < comps.length ; ++i ) {
         if( comps[i] instanceof TerminalGui ) {
             terminals.add(comps[i]);
         }
      }
   return terminals.toArray(new TerminalGui[terminals.size()])

}
```

Comment: you wrote `return list. ...` but I think you mean `return terminals. ...`.  I will mark this as correct answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Now I get some weird compiler error: ` Cannot instantiate the type List<TerminalGui>`. Maybe you've got something wrong here I do not see? (found it: `new ArrayList<TerminalGui>` is required here.)

Comment: oh yeah i am sorry, just mixed it up, should be fine now

Comment: Sry, didn't noticed it! Thanks a lot!